# Upgrading Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 stuck during "Installing the upgrades" -- what to do?

Tags: upgrade, system-installation, 13.10

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 and the upgrade manager asked if I wanted to upgrade so I said yes and the upgrade is running now.

The upgrade seems to have frozen at "Installing the upgrades". If I expand the Terminal window it says "Downloading Dropbox... 38%". It has been sitting at 38% for about an hour.

What should I do? Let it sit longer? Reboot? Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Update: here's what I did to fix it.

I noticed Dropbox was running in my status bar. So I right clicked on it and shut it down.

Then I checked the process list and it was still listed. So I shut it down with:

    sudo killall dropbox

That killed the process successfully and BOOM the upgrade instantly continued forward. It said Dropbox was installed successfully and kept going as if nothing happened. Yay!

Comment: Rather commenting you would have made it as a answer buddy @jim.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. I typed `sudo killall dropbox` on a different terminal and it worked for me, too. Basically why it works is because it stops the process that updates dropbox, then its update is skipped and it continues the os update.